# ¿Como puedo consultar varios ID en una misma consulta?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta de múltiples `ID` a la `base de datos` en una misma tabla.

La idea es seleccionar diferentes `Id` y enviarlos al controlador y que este me responda todos los datos de los `IDs` que he enviado.

Objeto roles que debo enviar:

```
[
    {
        "id": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 23
    },
    {
        "id": 11
    }
]
```

Mi controlador es:

```
@PostMapping("/public/varios")
    public List<Rol> listarPorId(@Valid @RequestBody Rol rol){
        Object id = rol.getId();
        return rolRepository.findById((Long) id);
    }
```

Al enviar el objeto roles me responde un error. Sé que no lo estoy haciendo bien, agradecería un ejemplo de como puedo implementar esto. Gracias

La respuesta deseada es:

```
[
{
  "id": 22,
  "nombre": "ROLE_USER",
  "fecha_creado": "2019-10-04",
  "fecha_modificado": "2019-10-18"
},
{
  "id": 23,
  "nombre": "ROLE_ADMIN",
  "fecha_creado": "2019-10-04",
  "fecha_modificado": "2019-10-18"
},
{
  "id": 11,
  "nombre": "ROLE_LECTURA",
  "fecha_creado": "2019-10-04",
  "fecha_modificado": "2019-10-18"
}
]
```

Repositorio

```
@Repository
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository<Rol, Serializable> {
    public List<Rol> getData(HashMap<String, Object> conditions);
    public abstract List<Rol> findById(Long id);
}
```

Comment: Puede mostrar el contenido de rolRepository?

Comment: Ya lo he añadido a la pregunta

Comment: En la practica nunca le puse abstract a los metodos del Repository, borra eso y prueba de vuelta

Comment: Cuando pruebo me sale este error: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `co.gov.risaralda.siete.rest.entity.Rol` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `co.gov.risaralda.siete.rest.entity.Rol` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si recibo una lista de roles (ids) me retorna como resultado esa lista, de lo contrario me retorna el listado completo de los roles

```
@PostMapping("/public/varios")
    public List<Rol> listarVarios(@RequestBody RolRequestIds ids){
        System.out.println(ids.getIds());
        if(ids.getIds()!=null){
            return rolRepository.findAllById(ids.getIds());
        }else {
            return rolRepository.findAll();
        }

    }

    static class RolRequestIds {
        private List<Long> ids;

        public List<Long> getIds(){
            if(ids.isEmpty()){
                return null;
            }else return ids;
        }
    }
```

Le envio los ids de esta manera:

```
{ids:[1,2,3]}
```

Espero que a alguien mas le sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que mencionar, primero, en tu controlador estás recibiendo una lista de roles no solamente uno (aunque solo estés mandando el puro Id), segundo, en tu clase `Rol` no sé como tengas declarada tu variable `Id` pero deberias tenerla como `Integer` al igual que en el método de tu repositorio, y para terminar en tu método del repo `List<Rol> findById(Long id);` el Id al ser único entonces no tiene caso regresar una lista de Rol por lo que tienes que regresar un unico Rol y como ya dije el Id debe ser Integer en lugar de Long, ahora, este método ya viene declarado por default en JPA solo que en lugar de regresarte un Rol te regresaría un `Optional<Rol>` por lo que deberías simplemente eliminar este método (o comentarlo).

Tu clase Rol:

```
public class Rol{
    private Integer id;
    // otras propiedades
    // setters and getters
}
```

Tu repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface RolRepository extends JpaRepository<Rol, 
    Serializable> {
    public List<Rol> getData(HashMap<String, Object> 
      conditions);
    // public abstract List<Rol> findById(Long id); <<-- este metodo no tienes que declararlo ya que viene implícito en JPA
}
```

Tu controlador:

```
@PostMapping("/public/varios")
public List<Rol> listarPorId(@Valid @RequestBody List<Rol> roles){
    List<Rol> resultado = new ArrayList();

    for(Rol rol : roles){
        Optional<Rol> r = rolRepository.findById(rol.getId());
        if(r.isPresent()){
            resultado.add(r.get());
        }            
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Nota: Yo nunca he usado el repositorio como tu lo tienes `extends JpaRepository<Rol,Serializable>` según tengo entendido en el segundo parámetro va el tipo del Id por lo que yo pondría `extends JpaRepository<Rol,Integer>`

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Fernando.. ya he publicado como resolví. Espero que a alguien mas le sirva